# HighChart - Group data by day

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a graph with 3 series and 4 points for each series. Each of these points corresponds to 4 different days (one point per day). That is to say that each day will have 3 points in total, since they are 3 series. But these 3 points differ in the hour, minutes and seconds.

What I want to do is keep this data in the X axis to show it in the Tooltip, but that the 3 points are aligned.

Let's show it with examples.

This is what I currently have:

```
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            type: 'spline'
        },

        colors: ['#3131F8', '#FB1C1C', '#008000', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9',
            '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#8085e8', '#8d4653', '#91e8e1'],

        yAxis: {
            opposite: false,
            showLastLabel: true,
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: "right"
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Tensión'
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled:  true
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function () {
                var n = this.series.name;
                var s = '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: <b>';
                    return s + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y / 1000), 2, '.') + ' kV</b><br/>';
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },

        series: [{"name":"Minima","pointInterval":86400000,"data":[[1538467200000,215.9],[1538581500000,217.6],[1538651700000,218],[1538728200000,218.5]]},{"name":"Maxima","pointInterval":86400000,"data":[[1538506800000,228.8],[1538530200000,228.4],[1538676000000,229.3],[1538779500000,228.8]]},{"name":"Promedio","pointInterval":86400000,"data":[[1538438400000,223.9365],[1538524800000,224.0667],[1538611200000,224.4135],[1538697600000,224.45]]}]
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZottoSL/8vedjxLs/5/

This is what I want (I modified the X point in the data to achieve the visual effect, but actually I want to keep it):

```
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            type: 'spline'
        },

        colors: ['#3131F8', '#FB1C1C', '#008000', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9',
            '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#8085e8', '#8d4653', '#91e8e1'],

        yAxis: {
            opposite: false,
            showLastLabel: true,
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: "right"
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Tensión'
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled:  true
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function () {
                var n = this.series.name;
                var s = '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: <b>';
                    return s + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y / 1000), 2, '.') + ' kV</b><br/>';
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },

        series: [{"name":"Minima","pointInterval":86400000,"data":[[1538438400000,215.9],[1538524800000,217.6],[1538611200000,218],[1538697600000,218.5]]},{"name":"Maxima","pointInterval":86400000,"data":[[1538438400000,228.8],[1538524800000,228.4],[1538611200000,229.3],[1538697600000,228.8]]},{"name":"Promedio","pointInterval":86400000,"data":[[1538438400000,223.9365],[1538524800000,224.0667],[1538611200000,224.4135],[1538697600000,224.45]]}]
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZottoSL/9bk8hq3n/1/

That is to say, that when drawing the graph on the X axis, only consider the year, month and day, discriminating the hour, minutes and seconds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired look by using dataGrouping. That way you don't have to do any extra processing. All you would need to do, is to give this definition:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [
        ['day', [1]]
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

To get the actual time of the point in the tooltip you could then do this:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormatter: function() {
    var n = this.series.name;
    var s = '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: <b>';
    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d - %H:%M', this.series.xData[this.index]) + s + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y / 1000), 2, '.') + ' kV</b><br/>';
  }
},
```

Where `Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d - %H:%M', this.series.xData[this.index])` gets the actual time of the point.

**Working JSFiddle Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/omfdy8nc/

**API on dataGrouping:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping

---

To remove the extra time that can be in front or after the series when dataGrouping is done per day we need to set a min and max value. The reason we have this whitespace is because the original data have values that are not exactly set at midnight per day.

Adding the following `load` event will find the minumum/maximum full day and set the `xAxis` and the navigator `xAxis` to these values:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      let extremes = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes()
      let min = extremes.dataMin - extremes.dataMin % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
        max = extremes.dataMax - extremes.dataMax % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
      this.update({
        xAxis: {
          min: min,
          max: max
        },
        navigator: {
          xAxis: {
            min: min,
            max: max
          }
        }
      }, true, false, false)
    }
  }
},
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/omfdy8nc/32/

**API on the load event:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.load

**API on chart.update:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: Excellent solution friend, this is what I was looking for! But something remained to be resolved. The series ends before the end of the graph, you can see a blank space to the right of it. Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Thank you, I have added a function that resolves the issue with whitespace at the end of the graph, and updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same timestamp for each point on the same day as `x` property and save the real timestamp in the point object for example as `realX`. Then use real timestamp in `tooltip.pointFormatter` to create show the real date for each point. Check the example posted below.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JS:

```
var data = [{
    name: "Minima",
    pointInterval: 86400000,
    data: [
      [1538467200000, 215.9],
      [1538581500000, 217.6],
      [1538651700000, 218],
      [1538728200000, 218.5]
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Maxima",
    pointInterval: 86400000,
    data: [
      [1538506800000, 228.8],
      [1538530200000, 228.4],
      [1538676000000, 229.3],
      [1538779500000, 228.8]
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Promedio",
    pointInterval: 86400000,
    data: [
      [1538438400000, 223.9365],
      [1538524800000, 224.0667],
      [1538611200000, 224.4135],
      [1538697600000, 224.45]
    ]
  }],
  finalData = [],
  i,
  j,
  series,
  point;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  series = data[i];
  finalData[i] = {
    name: series.name,
    pointInterval: series.pointInterval,
    data: []
  };

  for (j = 0; j < series.data.length; j++) {
    point = series.data[j];

    finalData[i].data.push({
      x: data[0].data[j][0],
      y: point[1],
      realX: point[0]
    });
  }
}

chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

  chart: {
    renderTo: "container",
    type: 'spline'
  },

  colors: ['#3131F8', '#FB1C1C', '#008000', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9',
    '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#8085e8', '#8d4653', '#91e8e1'
  ],

  yAxis: {
    opposite: false,
    showLastLabel: true,
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: "right"
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Tensión'
    }
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: true
  },

  tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
      var n = this.series.name,
        s = '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + n + '</span>: <b>',
        date = 'Date: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %H:%M', this.realX),
        number = Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y / 1000), 2, '.') + ' kV</b><br/>';
      return s + number + date;
    }
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },

  navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },

  series: finalData
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qfv1yzmh/1/

Comment: It is a great alternative solution. Thank you!